# How to set time to Central European timezone

Tags: php, sql, time, timezone

I have this SQL PHP code where I insert the NOW() time:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO logs (username, msg, color, Time) VALUES ('$uname', '$msg', '$color', NOW())";
```

Unfortunately, it gives me GMT rather than Central European Time. What can I do? I tried putting `date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Vienna');` Before it but it won't work.

Comment: I recommend you keep UNIX time in your DB, that is irrespective of time zone. You can then simply recalculate it in your PHP code when calling it from the DB...

Answer (score 0):

Get the time with PHP and insert inside the database. Servers time is diffrent as they may located at diffrent locations. In your case the value of timestamp will be inserted by the server.

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Vienna');
$time = date('d-m-Y H:i:s');
$sql = "INSERT INTO logs (username, msg, color, Time) VALUES ('$uname', '$msg', '$color', '$time')";
```

Comment: Hi Abhishek. But now it inserts 00-00-0000 00:00 in the database. I'm not inserting the current time anymore! How do I make it so that I insert the current time?

Comment: Set the timestamp column for mediumtext. If it is set for current time stamp then make it to none. You can do this by going to the `Structure > change.`